# composer install not working on Lavavel 4.2.3 install

Tags: laravel

I have pulled a git repo of a Laravel 4.2.3 Application.  When I run the command composer install, all dependencies are installed, I see the messages "Writing lock file" and "Generating autoload files" and then I get the error:

> {"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"file_put_contents(/var/www/maxim
>   izedmetabolix.com/app/storage/meta/services.json): failed to open
>   stream: No  such file or
>   directory","file":"/var/www/maximizedmetabolix.com/vendor/lar
>   avel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php","line":70}}

I get this same error anytime I try to run an artisan command.  I don't get this error at all with new laravel install's, but I did notice that the storage directory in the new installs is in the root folder.  In the 4.2.3 version, the error says it's looking for the storage directory under /app.  Would this be related to the issue?
I'm not sure if there was a structural change in the upgrade from 4 to 5, or if the composer install command is backwards compatible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the project may have .gitingore'd the storage directory so it is missing some needed files. Adding all the folders from a default install may be the solution.

Yes, there is a big structural difference between Laravel 4 and 5 (the storage folder is located in /app/storage for one)